# appending variable to be used jQuery validate plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have variable

```
var student_office_id = $(this).data('office');
```

and I am looking to use it in the jQuery validate plugin like so:

```
$('.office_directed_to, .degree_type').bind('change', function() {

  var student_office_id = $(this).data('office');

  $("#admin-form").validate({

    rules: {
      "h_number["+student_office_id+"]": {
        required: function(element) {
          return $("#office_directed_to-8").val() != '';  
        }
      },

      "degree_type["+student_office_id+"]": {
        required: function(element) {
          return $("#office_directed_to-"+student_office_id+).val() != '';  
        }
      }
    } // end rules
  }); // end validate
}); // end bing change
```

I receive the following error in the console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

It refers to the first line I try to append student_office_id in, I imagine it would return an error on the other instances too.

Comment: Can you paste the result of `console.log(student_office_id)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify keys in objects using variables in that way. You'll need to do the following:

```
var rules = {}

rules["h_number["+student_office_id+"]"] = {
    required: function(element) {
      return $("#office_directed_to-8").val() != '';  
    }
}

rules["degree_type["+student_office_id+"]"] = {
    required: function(element) {
      return $("#office_directed_to-"+student_office_id+"").val() != '';  
    }
}

$("#admin-form").validate({
    rules: rules // end rules
});
```

The key point is that you can use the array-like `[]` syntax with strings for accessing properties on objects, which will allow you to dynamically generate the key (as a string) using another variable's value.